# Chrome on IOS has a redirect loop in redux/react website

Tags: ios, google-chrome, reactjs, react-router, redux

So a weird bug that we have came across in `Google chrome on IOS`. There is a constant redirect loop occurring. We're using `React` and `React-router`.

I came across a weird fix which involved me adding a query string at the end - `/#/?_k=p8ttt0` - But this isn't something that we want to do as it's an odd looking string and will ruin the other routes.

Here is the some of the code that we're using.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { DevTools, DebugPanel, LogMonitor } from 'redux-devtools/lib/react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { syncReduxAndRouter } from 'redux-simple-router';

const store = configureStore();
const history = createBrowserHistory(); 

syncReduxAndRouter(history, store);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Router history={history} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
        <Route path="/" component={SiteContainer}>
          <IndexRoute component={HomeLayout} />
          <Route path="a" component={HomeLayout} />
          <Route path="b" component={HomeLayout} />
          <Route path="c" component={HomeLayout} />
          <Route path="d" component={HomeLayout} />

        </Route>
        <Route path="/styleguide" component={StyleguideComponent} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Has anyone came across this error before? If so is there a fix for it?

#### Update 1:

So I found out that replacing `createBrowserHistory` with `createHashHistory` fixes this issue but it still uses the ugly hash in the URL. Is there a way around this so I do not have to use this `createHashHistory` component? I mean what I could do is only use `createHashHistory` on specific devices (In this case `IOS` chrome, and any other browser that may have this problem).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a solution in a `GitHub` issue: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2565 - Basically this will tell you to update your `history` module to

`"history": "^2.0.0-rc3"`

I also updated my `React-router` module because I had an issue where my `react-router` version needed to be a specific version to support `2.0.0-rc3`

`"react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5"`